# Can a Dell Equallogic have an SMB share or are they only iSCSI?

Tags: iscsi, dell-equallogic

Is it possible to set up an SMB share on a Dell Equallogic 4100, or is it solely iSCSI?  I can't find anything but iSCSI.

I would like to access the data over SMB  (`\\myequallogic`) shares as opposed to an iSCSI drive

Comment: You have enough rep here to know we're not Google -- If you have a question about features on Dell hardware your first call should be ***To Dell***, not Server Fault.  Also it would be important to tell us what ***model*** Equallogic device you're talking about. Some are iSCSI only, some are iSCSI and CIFS...

Comment: PS4100.  I have used Google.  I cannot find an answer.  That's why I asked here.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the `PSxxxx` series EqualLogic SANs are just SANs (iSCSI providers). [Dell's technical specs seem to agree](http://www.equallogic.com/products/default.aspx?id=10881).

EqualLogic [FS Series systems](http://www.equallogic.com/products/default.aspx?id=10465) support CIFS/SMB and other protocols in addition to iSCSI.

Answer (score 1):

Dell Equallogic PS4xxx series do not provide SMB share functionality. It is purely an iSCSI SAN Appliance.  You will need a back end server to provide such a share.  Something like openfiler is a good open source storage server